# Long-lived ping program after resuming from suspend not receive pong

Tags: linux, sockets, ping, icmp

I wrote a [ping program](https://github.com/lilydjwg/winterpy/tree/master/pyexe/pingd) sending ICMP pings using non-privileged ICMP sockets on Linux. I let it running continously and record the RTT. But sometimes after resuming from suspend, all the ping requests go unanwsered.

I can see from wireshark that the ICMP ping requests are sent, but neither ping responses nor ICMP error messages are received.

When I start it again, or ping that IP address (which my program is pinging) with the command-line tool `ping`, it gets responses.

My IP address hasn't changed.

`strace` shows that the send syscall succeeded. Nothing special is found.

I'd like to know why this happen, or what steps should I do to dig out the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but.. 
 Check to see if the system when it suspends turns of the network port or not 
 It is possible that there is an issue in regards to that I had a similar issue with a windows system that would lock up any "active" network commands during standby as the network card turned "off" and reset.